# Removing item before specified parameter in Double Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm not sure how to link a two nodes together. I understand that in order to link the first one with the third one (because i'm removing the second one), I use something like crt.next = crt.next.next but how am i supposed to do link the node that node back?

Example:

X1 <> x2 <> X3 <> x4 <> x5
I want to remove x3.
so i link x2 to x4 by crt.next = crt.next.next
I don't know how to linke x4 back to x2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you do

```
crt.next = crt.next.next
```

you can do:

```
crt.next.prev = crt
```

since you want to link crt as the previous link from crt.next.

Comment: Oh really? Haha I thought that was a bit too simple for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Linking x4 to x2 would be

```
crt.next.next.prev=crt;
```

then you need to free x3 memory

```
free(x3);
```